# Blender VSE: What to do with 20gb SSD (performance enhancement/rendertime)?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

so my D drive has about 1 -2 gb of drivers on it. Otherwise there's over like 22gb of free space there. So let's say 20gb to be safe. Blender and everything else is on my C main hard drive.

How can I take advantage of this to improve blender vse performance and render times? I don't care about the 3d stuff so much atm.

Things that I'd like improved:
-render times are horribly long in my vse (if I'm rendering with the cpu it's in the 90% load rate in the task manager generally) I render to preview my work and make sure there's no errors, before creating the final render. Would writing it to the ssd and then viewing test copies there and then deleting afterwards greatly increase my render times?

-I have to use 25% proxies most of the time when doing any major editing. I can finetune with no proxy but its painfully laggy and slow, and things jump around and stutter and freeze.

-in my big project which is 20-30 mins of footage, it constantly reloads the strips when I zoom out. And its really laggy even with 25% proxy, and no proxy things jump around and freeze up. My fps has gone from the native 22.81 down bit by bit and its at a measly ~8fps even when I'm previewing blankspace at 25% proxy (there's alot of stuff in there atm). my ram is usually only up to 60% used tho when dealing with 25% proxy mode even tho it laggs so much, at no proxy tho the ram can hit the 90%'s and thats generally when it does freeze up for a second or two and studder)

Can I improve any of these with my 20gb of ssd that's inside my laptop there? Specifically what, and how would I go about doing it? Just note I do have the 1-2gb of drivers there (came pre-installed that way and some of them are dealing with backups and other important stuff). Otherwise I don't really know if the drive is even running or being used tbh. SO limited knowledge leads to hesitation to do anything too fancy.

Blender and all my video file are on my hard drive atm....and when I move file locations I have to always go in and re-select where the new location is or it won't showup in the vse. And I'm unsure if I'd have to do that for every strip I made a hardcut on, or every separate video clip or if there's an easy way to change the reference folder for LOTs of items rather than doing them all 1 by 1....or if I'm best only touching the ssd for future projects instead.

Would appreciate any insight, thxs. Please elaborate where possible, I'm not overly tech savy. People say it makes blender load up faster, that doesnt really do much as it loads fine alrdy. Its just moving stuff and interacting with the vse as well as rendering that I want help improving. Surely rendering would be better no? or does it not matter since encoding is the slow part and not the writing to disk?
I was looking at using my ssd as extra ram like u can do apparently with usb drives..? But apparently ssd don't work the same way or something, and are simple hard drive functionality? Is buying a large usb drive and using that as extra ram gonna be helpful as well? I think I can only upgrade my ram directly to 12gb or 16gb from my 8gb...or mbe not at all it might be soldered on the cpu

Comment: Unfortunately, VSE render is a single threaded process and the only way to drastically speed it up is to run multiple instances of Blender to load each core and then use FFmpeg Concatenate function to merge results

Comment: Theres an addon(?) I think that will do exactly what @Serge suggests

Answer (score 0):

It get faster renders from Blender VSE when I make sure to eliminate any scaling. My Canon cameras produce 1920x1088 footage. Set Blender to render at 1920x1088.

Comment: well i rendered without scalin  and its 11 hours for 25 min vid....hah

Comment: How is that an answer? it has nothing to do with the question and I originally already did eliminate scaling and as I stated the time was 11 hours for 25 mins of video. I made the OP and looked into what to do with my SSD because it WAS 11 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the recommendations on this page:

[How to import footage in the VSE for optimal playback and organization?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182692/how-to-import-footage-in-the-vse-for-optimal-playback-and-organization)

But don't expect miracles, until the VSE is developed further, the performance is sub-par compared to any other dedicated video editing app.